# Adding a ui:tab aura component in Lightning App

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, aura

Working in a Lightning App, and not sure if all Aura components are supported.

I am currently trying to implement `ui:tabset`, as follows:

```
<aura:component >
    <ui:tabset class="tabset">
    <ui:tab title="Tab 1">
        <p>Tab 1</p>
            Tab 1 Content
    </ui:tab>
    <ui:tab title="Tab 2" >
         <p>Tab 2</p>
             Tab 2 Content
         </ui:tab>
    <ui:tab title="Tab 3" active="{!true}" >
        <p>Tab 3</p>
              Tab 3 Content
    </ui:tab>
    <ui:tab title="Tab 4" >
        <p>Tab 4</p>
               Tab 4 Content
    </ui:tab>
</ui:tabset> 
</aura:component>
```

When saving, I receive the following error -

```
Failed to save undefined: No COMPONENT named tabset found: Source
```

Is `ui:tabset` not available in Lightning components, or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ui:tabset` is available as part of the open-source Aura Framework, and not for Lightning Components. You can view the list of supported components in your org by going to `https://<mySalesforceInstance>.lightning.force.com/auradocs/reference.app`, where `<mySalesforceInstance>` is the name of the instance hosting your org; for example, na1.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_doc_app.htm

---

**EDIT: November 26, 2016**

The [tabset](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_tabset.htm) component is available now under ligthning namespace `lightning:tabset` however it is still in BETA.

Comment: That's where I'm currently at - very limited subset.  Anyway to enable the additional components?

Comment: The components are part of the release, so you're seeing what's there. We plan to release additional components in future releases.

Answer (score 1):

There's a tab component available in the SLDSX package on GitHub:

https://github.com/ForceDotComLabs/sldsx