# error saving lightning component ui:block

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

I tried creating something with a `ui:block` in a lightning component.

I get this message in the dev console: Failed to save undefined: No COMPONENT named block found: Source

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">
  <ui:block>
    <h4>test</h4>
  </ui:block>
</aura:component>
```

According to the `aura:docs`, `ui:block` is GA.  Same result with some other GA UI components like `ui:listView`.

Comment: I have had the same problem with this as well as other apparently "supported" components. If you navigate to `https://<YOURINSTANCE>.lightning.force.com/auradocs/reference.app` you'll find out that these components even though are documented in the official docs, are not present in the reference app. That means that these components not available to your org for some reason. I'm struggling to find an answer to this too. This is part of my question that I posted earlier - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/81562/input-type-range-not-working-on-ios

Comment: I encountered this issue as well.  Is there another way to execute a lightning event on the click of a div then?  The aura:click doesn't seem to work for me either.

Comment: <div onclick="{!c.handleClick}">...</div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, apparently not all aura components are released yet to **lightning**, but they're documented and are part of the open source framework as per [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/67364/adding-a-uitab-aura-component-in-lightning-app). This means that it's a waiting game. In the meantime we'll need to find other alternatives with HTML/CSS/JavaScript in order to replicate the functionality of these components inside the lightning components. If you were to build your own app outside lightning, using the [open source framework](https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura), then you can use these components.

Comment: Lightning Components is based on Aura, but it's not simply Aura loaded from a static resource. The reference app and the Lightning Component docs are the primary references to consult.

Comment: The above notwithstanding, many of the components might not be live in Lightning yet, but are pretty simple and you could implement them yourself. The source to `ui:block` is located here: https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura/tree/master/aura-components/src/main/components/ui/block. There's no serverside call or even javascript, so this one you can just make in your own org and use as needed.